# batch script to reset Internet Explorer

Tags: batch-file, web, browser, reset

I am looking for a way to reset Internet Explorer and possibly all the other browsers by using a single batch script for ease of access. As much as I have is a way to remove all current data from firefox using

```
RD /S /Q "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
RD /S /Q "%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox"
```

but I am more or less looking to reset it while preserving the browsers yet.

Any info or suggestions would be more than welcome!

Comment: Reset all basic settings, toolbars, extentions, addons, back to defaults without removing bookmarks

Comment: Well, Internet Explorer stores a lot of its settings in the registry, I think … so first of all you would have to find out which settings are stored where, and then you could export them into a `.reg` text file that can be imported again …